# Applescript Loop inside Loop (repeat)

Tags: curl, web-scraping, applescript

**What am i doing wrong that the following applescript does not:**

1. Loading Search Keywords from a .txt file
2. Getting links from constructed URL's : set url to "https://teespring.com/search?q="  & "one keyword from" .txt file
3. Return all links from these constructed URL's.

**P.S. Is the URL fetching and href filtering possible in pure curl only?**

-

```
tell application "Finder"  
  set myPath to container of (path to me) as text -- SET MAIN PATH  
  set Keywords to read file (myPath & "KEYWORDS.txt") as «class utf8» using delimiter linefeed
end tell  

set site_url to "https://teespring.com/search?q="  

tell application "Safari"  
  repeat with Keyword in Keywords  
  make new document  
  set URL of front document to site_url & Keyword  
  delay 10  


  set theLinks to {}  
  tell application "Safari" to set num_links to (do JavaScript "document.links.length" in document 1)  
  set linkCounter to num_links - 1  

  -- retrieve the links  
  repeat with i from 0 to linkCounter  
  tell application "Safari" to set end of theLinks to do JavaScript "document.links[" & i & "].href" in document 1  
  end repeat  


  repeat until ((do JavaScript "document.readyState" in front document) is "complete")  

  delay 10  
  end repeat  
  close front document  
  end repeat
```

[image]

Thank you everyone

Daniel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the solution:

```
tell application "Finder"
    set myPath to container of (path to me) as text
    set theKeywords to read file (myPath & "KEYWORDS.txt") as «class utf8» using delimiter linefeed
end tell

set keyword_urls to "https://teespring.com/search?q="


set listCount to count of theKeywords
set site_url to {}
repeat with i from 1 to listCount
    set end of site_url to keyword_urls & item i of theKeywords
end repeat
```